# How to discover open file descriptors in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a situation where we have an AWS Lambda written in Java that routinely runs out of file descriptors. AWS Lambda's have a limit of 1024 file descriptors. And we seem to be hitting that limit frequently but are unsure why. 
One thing we're not sure about: if a java lambda leaked a resource, then its container is suspended and then later re-hydrated, do those leaked resources remain or does the invocation receive a whole new sandbox?

We *believe* that we might have a resource leak that's surviving invocations of the lambda. If we make a change to the lambda (like deploying a new version, changing environment variables etc.) it seems the file descriptor issue goes away for a time.

The nature of the lambda is pretty simple, its invoked by a kinesis event, reads from an s3 bucket, extracts some information, and then writes to a dynamo table. We've extensively checked to make sure we're closing all of resources so we actually think that if there is a resource leak, it might be in one of the dependencies we're using.

Is there an easy way to see what file descriptors are associated with a java application from code, and one that itself does not open another descriptor?

Comment: hard to believe anything about lambda persists between invocations.  I think you might be missing the fact that sockets are also file descriptors -- m.b. you are not closing your sockets (e.g. database connections?) correctly.

Comment: No, I knew the sockets are file descriptors. It's also why I asked about checking without opening another descriptor - running a shell command from within java will create a new pipe descriptor for example. And we know for a fact that some things do survive: "Any declarations in your Lambda function code (outside the handler code, see Programming Model) remains initialized, providing additional optimization when the function is invoked again" (see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html). Not sure if that extends to descriptors though.

Comment: well, what's wrong with running a shell command?  Sure it will require a file descriptor, but don't wait to do it after you get your error, do it all the time and see which file descriptors are not getting closed before you run out.